# what encryption does android uses for https using httpsurlconnection and defaulthttpclient

Tags: android, ssl, encryption

I would like to know what encryption algorithm does android uses while we make a connection using httpsurlconnection or via defaulthttpclient.

And also what is the key size ?

And is there any difference between the default encryption implementation for httpsurlconnection and defaulthttpclient.

By the way I am implementing certificate pinning with custom sslsocketfactory like in this link mentioned below

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/186599/SSL-Verification-for-Android-Applications

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single answer. TLS can use any of dozens of cipher suites, depending what suites are supported by both server and client. It has nothing to do with HttpsURLConnection or HttpClient. Or certificate pinning.

Comment: How about if i want to just use aes 256.. is that possible with the sslsocketfactory... if so how ?